# Tomcat Memory Consumption

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, tomcat7, heap-memory

I am going to install Tomcat on linux with JVM Heap size as 2048m(2GB) to 2304m(2GB+256MB) 
by setting `CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2304m"` in `cataina.sh file` 
and the Linux OS have 8GB of the RAM 
so i am making some points , please help with this

- Should tomcat consume directly 2GB from OS?
- If no to above ,then how much it should take?
- If memory is taken by the tomcat is less than 2GB then this 2GB memory allocated by os for this tomcat is only used for this only or some app can use this memory?
- and finally we are setting the this max and min memory , means OS allocates all that amount of the memory  for tomcat?

Answer (score 8):

The JVM will pre-allocate whatever memory you specify for `-Xms`. So, it will request and allocate 2GB of memory at startup. If it needs more memory later (up to `-Xmx`), the JVM will request more memory from the OS.

But, do you know you need this much memory? The main driver of memory consumption will be your application, *not* Tomcat. Simple webapps with a few servlets or JSPs can easily run in less than 32MB of heap. You need to measure your application for performance / load to determine the optimal setting.

A side note - the preferred method for setting JVM parameters is with the `JAVA_OPTS` setting in `setenv.sh`, not catalina.sh.

Comment: thanks for the response .Yesterday i deployed tomcat with above setting and i found that tomcat is taking only the 200MB - 300MB of memory as from the linux top command and not the 2GB of the memory . SO should make conclusion that 2GB is reserved memory and not allocated .Please help with this

Comment: I think the JVM may not be picking up your -Xms / -Xmx settings. Try moving them to JAVA_OPTS in setenv.sh.

Comment: NO JVM is picking up the path params , i checked through jvisualvm. It is taking up 2GB as from the jvisualvm , but OS is showing only 200MB -300MB.

Comment: I started a JVM with -Xms 1024M and I see VIRT=1104m and RES=168m in top. So it looks like the process requests the full amount of virtual memory, but hasn't actually touched all of it to make the OS physically allocate it.